# Switch on /off photo sync between Mac and Iphone

Tags: macos, sync, iphone, photos

I am using Photos on Mac. Strangely, whenever I take a photo on my iPhone, I can also see the photo in the Photos app on the Mac. I guess there is some sync going on there. But, I looked into the preferences of Photos on the Mac and found out that no sync is enabled (see screenshot).  How could I actually switch on/off the sync?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to iPhone, Settings, your name (includes iCloud), iCloud, and then Manage Storage, and then go through Photos and then Disable and Delete.

Assuming you do this, you have 30 days to download your photos and videos.